# Java - Performance Questions; variable names and file name length

Tags: java, performance, file, variables

Well just some questions about performance, but i think some of the questions are logical:
- If i use variables with short names will be better/faster to process?
Example: "String s", will be better than "String superphrase".
- About the file names, if the file name is short will be faster to access it?
Example: (almost the same) filename.txt or f.txt.

Thanks to all guys, i really like to make my software as better as i can :)

Comment: you should consider making an efficient code instead of this. AFAIK it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I' also interested in whether and how much length of variable name impact performance. I don't think name would be erased after compiled because the existence of reflect. If name length does impact performance a lot, I can choose some tools to shrink and minimize the code, which would not affect readability.

Answer (score 10):

> If i use variables with short names will be better/faster to process?

**No.** Variable names might not even be in your resulting bytecode. In the end of the day variables are mapped to registers/stack operands. Variable name is irrelevant. It's only for human beings. And they tend to prefer `superPhrase` over `s`.

> if the file name is short will be faster to access it

**No.** Files, just like variables, are referenced using special identifiers (e.g. inodes). File name is only needed when opening/locating a file. And it's several orders of magnitude faster compared to actual file access. This applies equally to Java applications and other OS processes.

Comment: The compiler could use a few nanoseconds longer, though, and this is, of course, a horrible performance impact a bloody greenhorn must avoid at all costs.

Comment: @Ingo Compiler is not going to run the s/w all the time.So it doesn't matter , i think.

Comment: @Arpit Is your sarcasm detector out of order? Sure it doesn't run it, but it must compile it, and then, as I said, longer varaible names and string constants will take a bit more CPU to process, all other things being equal.

Comment: let the compiler take the time but once the s/w is published it's not to be compiled again.

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer, i'll work with comfortable variables instead of short ones from now and on, anyway why if i compile a project with 200 letters long and then the same project with 1 letter long, the 200 letters long takes more space if it's supposed to be the same? just curious, and again thanks :)

Comment: @Mayhem7: field names are always stored in bytecode and local variable names are stored if `-g` option is used (compare with `-g:none`). But the presence of variable names in bytecode has little to no impact on performance.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent answer by Tomasz, you display all the signs of early optimisation. There's several issues:

1) Until you hit a problem you don't know what to optimise for: reducing CPU usage is a different optimisation from reducing memory or reducing disk usage

2) Optimisation costs time, which is either your personal time (which has value) or your company's time (which has a more easily equatable value). Optimisation where it is not necessary is a waste of money.

3) Reducing variable length (even if it did make a difference) would be irrelevant if the important thing to optimise is 'time spent by a programmer to work out what the software does'. Readable code is important - good variable names are an important part of that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your tips, i work for my own not company, and i'm areally tidy person and like a good work, so don't care about spend a bit more time to make a nice software, if you go to a hospital with a cut in the arm you don't want a simple band aid, you want wound points.

Comment: @GotyMetal But you don't even know what you're optimising for. Memory? CPU time? There's always trade offs. And 'good work' is readable, understandable code.