# How to understand 'let' in 'for' statement?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-5

As far as I know, 'let' is used for declaring block variable. But it can't declare twice with same name. For example:

```
'use strict';
let a = 1;
let a = 2; // syntax error
```

So how to separate each scope in 'for' iteration with the same variable name?

```
'use strict';
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    });
}
// output: 
// 0
// 1
// 2
```

Dose interpreter change the variable name silently? Any info will be appreciated.

<strike>I don't think is a duplicated question. Because I really want to ask is the conflict between two theory.</strike>

Comment: I don't think is duplicated. I want to know the conflict between two principles.

Comment: You can try running your code in [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=GYewTgFANgpgLgAgJYILwIAwG5kIDwIDMOSA1KQJQDeAsAFAKMIDO8AKkgLYwgCucEYLwB2AYzhIQwiNXpN5CUVOYhYAOiggA5hCQUscpgF999I0A) to get an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`let` scopes your variable to the block it's in.
After you've assigned a scope to `a`, you can't overwrite it. So the second time you use let, it can't handle that.

Correct usage would be:

```
'use strict';
let a = 1;
a = 2;
```

Comment: The question is not about the first code block, but how it works in a for loop.

Comment: The first code is OP stating that he understands how `let` works. He is asking for `let` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop , i is declaring at the beginning only and in each iteration it change the value of it .

let is used to variable that you will write there value again .

In the first example you define variable with name 'a' so you cant define another with same name , but you can change it value , which happened in the for loop.

Comment: Not true. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473350/let-keyword-in-the-for-loop), every iteration `i` will get a new binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
let a = 1;
let a = 2; // syntax error

'use strict';
let a = 1;
var a = 2; this will overwrite...
```

here you specified a value already.. your intention is , it shouldn't change in runtime. so you cant able to change it once declared in block with same type `let` ..

that why you getting this error..

intention of `let` is value should not change..

in loop ,
it will be separate on iterate.. so it print value on runtime. so it wont overwrite it...

Answer (score 0):

let allows to create the variable once, but the value of the variable can be changed, 
example -

```
     let t =5// 
    let t = 6 // throws an errow but 
    t =7 
 console.log(t) - gives 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the variable `a` is defined twice in the same scope. This gives you an error because the variable already exists. `let` doesn't allow this, redeclaring with `var` does. This is one advantage of using `let`.

```js
var a = 3;
var a = 2;

console.log(a); // 2

let b = 3;
let b = 2; //syntax error

let c = 3;
var c = 2; //also a syntax error
```

In a for loop, the `i` variable has a different scope. Meaning these two `i` variables here **aren't** the same.

```js
let i = "my string";
console.log(i); //my string

for(let i = 1; i <= 3; ++i){
  console.log(i); //1, 2, 3
  
}

console.log(i); //my string
```

The javascript runtime doesn't care if your variable is named the same. It will differentiate the scope and thus the reference to the variable. It's replacing your reference to `i` whichs value is 4 to the new variable in the for loop.

I have an answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303349/does-variable-name-length-matter-for-android-application-performance/36303617#36303617) on Stackoverflow which describes how the Android compiler doesn't care about your variable names. It's the same here, the runtime uses different "names" (different memory addresses).

Comment: @Ivar your right, gonna change it right away

Answer (score 0):

In the loop the variable is not declared again but only its value is incremented. 
It is similar to the following:

```
'use strict';
 let i = 0;
 i = i + 1;
```

consider the code being iterated again and again until the condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

`for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    // code
}`

step:

1. `let i = 0`
2. checkout `i<3`
3. exec `code`
4. `i++`, equals `i = i + 1`  // not occur error, while `let i = i + 1` will occur exception
5. loop step-2 until `i<3 == false`